# Hiding divs dynamically using a search

Tags: javascript

JSFiddle for what I have done so far http://jsfiddle.net/chQ2T/3/

As you can see, I have some divs arranged thus

```
<div id = "container">
    <div id = "abc" class = "box">
        ABC        
    </div>
    <div id = "cde" class = "box">
        CDE
    </div>
    <div id = "efg" class = "box">
        EFG
    </div>    
</div>
```

And there is a search box where I want to dynamically hide and show divs based on the search query (executed after every stroke) and the div id. So typing `c` should hide all divs where the id does not contain substring "c" i.e. the last one.

Typing `d` after that should hide the additional div abc, since it does not contain the substring "cd". Backspace should restore it. So basically it's a standard dynamic search.

What is missing are the Javascript functions for hiding and showing.

```
function hide_divs(search) {
    $("#container").not("#"+search).hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search_field").keyup(function() {
        var search = $.trim(this.value);
            hide_divs(search);
    });
});
```

I am struggling with restoring the previously hidden divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/chQ2T/4/

The `hide_divs()` function has been slightly modified to first hide all divs and then show only those that match.

```
function hide_divs(search) {
    $("#container > div").hide(); // hide all divs
    $('#container > div[id*="'+search+'"]').show(); // show the ones that match
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search_field").keyup(function() {
        var search = $.trim(this.value);
        hide_divs(search);
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thanks. I have added another function for when the search text is clear. http://jsfiddle.net/chQ2T/5/ Is there any way I can show all the divs that were hidden from the start?

Comment: Oh wait I know, it's just. `$("#container > div").show();`. Thanks again.