# Converting a datatable example from select to input

Tags: jquery

I have tried far too long tonight...
How do i convert

http://live.datatables.net/ribezoho/20/edit

into input fields instead of select option values?

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
    var select = $('<input type="text" placeholder='+title+' value="" />')
```

replace line

```
    .on( 'change', function () {
```

with

```
    .on( 'keyup', function () {  // column will be searched dynamically on key press
```

and

```
    .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
```

with

```
    .search( $.trim(this.value) ) // search for string which is entered
```

and this is no longer required

```
    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
    } );
```

Comment: but then it does not function properly?

Comment: look at this     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807236/hiding-divs-dynamically-using-a-search

Comment: replace line  ".on( 'change', function () {"   with   ".on( 'keyup', function () {"  and ".search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )"    with   " .search( $.trim(this.value) )"