# How to perform search function after using jQuery add data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(function(){
    var roles = ["Admin", "User", "Dealer", "Agent", "Buyer", "Guest", "User", "Dealer", "Agent"];

    $.each(roles, function(){
      $(".role_wrapper_2").append("<div class='roles_approval'><span>" + this + "</span></div>");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="role_wrapper_2">
  <div class="admin2_search">
    <form>
      <input class="role-search-approval" type="search" placeholder="Enter your keyword">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use jQuery to add some data when page is load and also add a search box for user to find these data more quickly and it will search word by word.

For example, just type "a" it will find all data include "a" or type "ab" it will find all data that include "ab".

What can I do to implement this search function?

Comment: use jquery keyup function

Comment: Here is an example    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807236/hiding-divs-dynamically-using-a-search

Comment: By include, do you mean for example typing "a" should include as matched word "Dealer" or just words starting with "a"?  That's said, usually this should be done like that, using `datalist` element: http://jsfiddle.net/1dbqwp6f/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could push all jquery elements to an array and then iterate over the `roles` array and perform an `.indexOf()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(function(){
    var roles = ["Admin", "User", "Dealer", "Agent", "Buyer", "Guest", "User", "Dealer", "Agent"];
    
    var elements = [];

    $.each(roles, function(){
      var element = $("<div class='roles_approval'><span>" + this + "</span></div>");
      elements.push(element);
      $(".role_wrapper_2").append(element);
    });
    
    $(".role-search-approval").on("keyup" /* or input event*/, function() {
      var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
      for(var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
        if(roles[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1) {
          elements[i].show();
        } else {
          elements[i].hide();    
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="role_wrapper_2">
  <div class="admin2_search">
    <form>
      <input class="role-search-approval" type="search" placeholder="Enter your keyword">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to push them to an extra array, you could loop through `$(".roles_approval")` on `keyup`and perform the indexOf on the text content.

```
$(".role-search-approval").on("keyup" /* or input event*/, function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
    $(".roles_approval").each(function() {
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();    
        }
    });
});
```